# emacs choose one of the parts of the window

Tags: emacs, emacs23

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch between visible buffers in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671819/how-to-switch-between-visible-buffers-in-emacs)

I'm using C-x 2 for splitting editor place to two parts. For choose one of them I use mouse now. How I can choose one of them using keyboard?

Comment: Note that in Emacs' terminology, the "parts of the window" are actually "windows in the frame". i.e. Each "part" is called a "window", and there may be multiple windows within a single frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use C-x o to move the cursor to the next window in the windows list.  See Steve Yegge's post [Effective Emacs](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/effective-emacs) for info.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate. See all of the following:

- [How to switch between visible buffers in emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671819/how-to-switch-between-visible-buffers-in-emacs)
- [I have multiple windows in Emacs, (C-x o) will take me to the "other" window, what does other mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400428/i-have-multiple-windows-in-emacs-c-x-o-will-take-me-to-the-other-window-wha)
- [In Emacs, what is the opposite function of other-window (C-x o)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143072/in-emacs-what-is-the-opposite-function-of-other-window-c-x-o)
- [Changing window faster in Emacs (or repeating last shortcut with a single strike)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046597/changing-window-faster-in-emacs-or-repeating-last-shortcut-with-a-single-strike)
- [Better window navigation in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858958/better-window-navigation-in-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

I added this line in my `.emacs` configuration file. Use Ctrl+TAB to navigate across the buffers.

```
(global-set-key [C-tab] 'other-window)
```